# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: unexpected token: (

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, jpa-2.0

I am getting the following Error When I try to execute the below query-

Error

```
ERROR [2014-10-27 11:17:24,264] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:33: unexpected token: (
ERROR [2014-10-27 11:17:24,304] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:33: unexpected token: (
! antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: (

ERROR [2014-10-27 11:17:24,306] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:68: unexpected token: MAX
ERROR [2014-10-27 11:17:24,312] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:68: unexpected token: MAX
! antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: MAX
```

Query

```
String sSubQuery =  "SELECT om.path, om.originalSize, MAX(om.lastModified) "+
                    "FROM "+
                    "ObjectMetadata om "+
                    "WHERE om.informationStoreId = '"+informationStoreDefinitionID+"' "+
                    "GROUP BY om.path, om.originalSize";

             String sQuery =  "SELECT SUM(o.originalSize) "+
                    "FROM "+
                    "("+
                    " "+sSubQuery+
                    " ) "+
                    "o";

            Query q = getEm().createQuery(sQuery);
```

Please Help.

Comment: Since you aren't using `MAX(om.lastModified)` in the outer query, you could just omit it. In fact, since you are just summing the `om.originalSize` with a filter, you don't need the derived table at all?

Comment: Table contains meta-data of the files and it may have multiple entries correspond to the file name but it has different-different last modified date in the Table. What I need is - a total size of all files that are recently updated or modified.

Comment: When I am executing the following query in postgres it successfully executed - `select sum(o.original_size) from(SELECT om.path,om.original_size,
              MAX(om.last_modified) FROM object_metadata om WHERE om.information_store_id =
              'ff0dcb68-8aab-40f0-b8d8-fcfb82396f5d' GROUP BY om.path,om.original_size) o";`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603496/org-hibernate-hql-errors-in-hql-subquries

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String sSubQuery = "SELECT SUM(om.originalSize), MAX(om.lastModified) "+ 
                   "FROM "+ "ObjectMetadata om "+ 
                   "WHERE om.informationStoreId = :informationStoreDefinitionID "+ 
                   "GROUP BY om.path, om.originalSize";

Query q = getEm().createQuery(sQuery);
q.addParameter("informationStoreDefinitionID",22);
```

Comment: @StuartLC I need to apply `sum` on the result of `sub query` for `Max(lastModified)`. So `Sum()` need to apply on all the record with have `max` `lastModified` date only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603496/org-hibernate-hql-errors-in-hql-subquries