# org.hibernate.hql Errors in HQL subqueries

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a `Table` which has `meta-data` of the `files`. The `Table` has `columns` `id, path, originalSize, lastModified and info_id`;

```
id, path,  lastModified,  originalSize, infoid
01, A.txt,   25/10/2014,  25,                 0
02, A.txt,   26/10/2014,  30,                 0
03, B.txt,   25/10/2014,  40,                 0
04, B.txt,   27/10/2014,  50,                 0
05, C.txt,   25/10/2014,  10,                 0
06, C.txt,   26/10/2014,  20,                 0
07, D.txt,   25/10/2014,  5,                  0
08, D.txt,   27/10/2014,  10,                 0
```

**I need a `sum` on the `originalSize` column where the `path` is one of some given list of `paths` and the `lastModified` is maximum of all the rows with that `path';**

I could not achieve the result in a single `HQL Query` so I did it in three steps:

**STEP 1:** In step 1, I am trying to get those rows which matches the criteria where the `path` is one of some given list of `paths` and the `lastModified` is maximum of all the rows with that `path'.

**STEP 2:** In step 2, I simply collecting only ids from the above result set for further Query.

**STEP 3:** I am trying to get the `sum` on `size` which matches with above `ids`.

**In detail with code and example;**

**STEP 1:**

I want to select all rows where the `path` is one of some given list of `paths` and the `lastModified` is maximum of all the rows with that `path';

```
id, filename, lastmodified
    02, A.txt,   26/10/2014 
    04, B.txt,   27/10/2014 
    06, C.txt,   26/10/2014 
    08, D.txt,   27/10/2014
```

I have written the following method using `HQL` which returns the above result;

```
public List<ObjectMetadata> getListOfLatestModifiedFiles(String infoId) {

        List<ObjectMetadata> objectMetadataList =null;
        try {



            String sQuery =  "SELECT om.id, om.path, om.originalSize, MAX(om.lastModified) "+
                    "FROM "+
                    "ObjectMetadata om "+
                    "WHERE om.infoId = '"+infoId+"' "+
                    "GROUP BY om.id, om.path, om.originalSize";
            org.hibernate.Query query = getEm().getSession().createQuery(sQuery);
            objectMetadataList = query.list();

            } catch (Exception nre) {
            System.out.println(nre.toString());

        }
        return objectMetadataList;
    }
```

**STEP 2:**

Now, I need only `IDs` from the `above result`;

```
    id
    02
    04
    06
    08
```

To get only IDs,  I have written another method which traverse the `List<ObjectMetadata>` and return only the `id`;

```
public List<String> getIds(List<ObjectMetadata> objectMetadataList) {
        List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
       try{
           Iterator itr = objectMetadataList.iterator();
           while(itr.hasNext()) {
               Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
               String id = String.valueOf(obj[0]);
               ids.add(id);
           }
        } catch (Exception nre) {
            System.out.println(nre.toString());
        }
        return ids;
    }
```

**STEP 3:**

Finally, I need the `sum` on `originalSize` column that matches with these IDs;

id, originalSize

```
02, 30
04, 50
06, 20
08, 10
```

`SUM` = `110`

For that I have written another method:

```
public long getSizeOfAllLatestModifiedFiles(List<String> list) {

        Long size  = 0l;
             String sQuery =  "SELECT SUM(om.originalSize) "+
                    "FROM "+
                    "ObjectMetadata om "+
                    "WHERE om.id IN (:ids) ";

        org.hibernate.Query query = (Query) getEm().getSession().createQuery(sQuery);
        query.setParameterList("ids", list);
        size  = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
        return size;
    }
```

**NOW MY ISSUE IS: I COULD NOT MAKE ALL THESE 3 STEPS, RUN IN A SINGLE QUERY**

I tried the below single query;

```
    String sSubQuery =  "SELECT om.path, om.originalSize, MAX(om.lastModified) "+
            "FROM "+
            "ObjectMetadata om "+
            "WHERE om.infoId = '"+infoId+"' "+
            "GROUP BY om.path, om.originalSize";

     String sQuery =  "SELECT SUM(o.originalSize) "+
            "FROM "+
            "("+
            " "+sSubQuery+
            " ) "+
            "o";
```

But on the below line of code;

```
 Query q = getEm().createQuery(sQuery);
```

I am getting the following Errors.

```
ERROR [2014-10-27 11:17:24,264] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:33: unexpected token: (
ERROR [2014-10-27 11:17:24,304] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:33: unexpected token: (
! antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: (

ERROR [2014-10-27 11:17:24,306] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:68: unexpected token: MAX
ERROR [2014-10-27 11:17:24,312] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:68: unexpected token: MAX
! antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: MAX
```

**Please help me to run all above 3 steps into a single HQL query**

Comment: so you throw away JPA and use Hibernate-specifics for no benefit? Hmmm

Comment: I am new to `JPA` and `Hibernate`. Initially I tried with `Criteria Builder` and `Detached Criteria`. But on executing that Query, it was throwing exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: No explicit selection and an implicit one cold not be determined. I Looked for exception and map the properties but it did not work. So I am looking for the HQL query and then I will try to make that query using `Criteria Builder` and `Detached Criteria`.

Comment: that is no reason to ignore JPA standard, and go direct to hibernate specifics when JPQL standard syntax would do that query. Go back to your question, and make it JPA-specific without Hibernate sessions etc, and a JPQL string and then what error you get for that JPQL

Comment: @ Neil Stockton Please suggest as I am new to JPA. If I replace `query` from `org.hibernate.Query` to `javax.persistence.Query` and create query using `getEm().createQuery(sQuery);` instead of `getEm().getSession().createQuery(sQuery);` then will it be JPQL standard Query or you are suggesting me to create query using `Criteria Builder and Detached Criteria`?

Comment: If you don't know what is standard JPQL then there are ample tutorials on the web and in the docs for each JPA implementation. Your query error tells you all you need to know ... attempting to put a SUBQUERY in the FROM clause is not valid, you have the WHERE clause